# Search selected text in current page on MacOS

Tags: macos, firefox, search

In Windows and GNU/Linux, Ctrl+F will look for the selected text in the current page.

I use this a lot and expected Command + F to do the same on MacOS, but it doesn't work (at least on Firefox). It does open the search menu, but it doesn't paste the selected text in it.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, I found that we can do:

⌘+F, then ⌘+E

I'm interested though if someone can provide a shorter way.

Comment: how did you discover that ?! :O I just found it on [this](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/find-highlighted-text/3852/4) SublimeText forum, and apparently you can also reverse the order: ⌘+E, then ⌘+F

Answer (score 1):

Try ⌘+F

Many common key combinations work that way, e.g.:

- Copy: CTRL+C ➔ ⌘+C
- Paste: CTRL+V ➔ ⌘+V
- Cut: CTRL+X ➔ ⌘+X
- Find: CTRL+F ➔ ⌘+F

There is also a really nice (free) application called [CheatSheet](https://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/) that will show you the available shortcuts when holding the ⌘ key for a short time:
[image]

Comment: +1 for the nice app, but it doesn't solve the problem. I made the question clearer.

Comment: Ah, I have misunderstood your question. Unfortunately I'm not sure on how to achieve what you want. I have just check and I have the same behavior with Firefox on my Mac. Probably a limitation of the application. I also wasn't able to find anything on this limitation at Mozilla...

Answer (score 1):

In the url bar, go to `about:config`
(acknowledge the warning that you can break things)

Find `accessibility.typeaheadfind.prefillwithselection` and double-click so change it to `true`.

The change is active immediately.